# Htaccess rules to rewrite pages inside folder to the root?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The is my *real* folder scheme:

```
ROOT
index.html
news.html
+articles
|-obama.html
|-oil.html
```

I want some htaccess rule so if people go to `domain.com/obama.html` the server will fetch the one in the `articles` folder without redirecting.

If some one goes to `domain.com/index.html` will still fetchs the one in the `articles` even if there is an index in the `ROOT`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond articles/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ articles/$1 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use:

```
# RewriteRule /obama.html$ /articles/obama.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/{index,news}.html$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /articles/$1 [L]
```

?

Comment: But there is tons of pages right there and they are dynamically created, so maybe your rule is only for obama.html?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule .* articles/$1 [L,QSA]
```